# Would usage in past tense

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

I have read this in "The Hindu" newspaper of India

> But in 1879 he **would** hit the jackpot as it were and bring out the blockbuster that would reverberate across the world.

Why **would** is used here?? Does this mean "it was about to hit jackpot"?  Also what does "as it were" means??

Comment: _As it were_ means that 'hitting the jackpot' is a metaphor; the person achieved a financial success, not literally a gambling win.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, something which is going to happen in future is being described in past, so the use of would is there for the same nous. The use of "as it were" characterizes the preceding term.

Comment: Yes - presumably the previous sentence was about the person's life before 1879, when the event being referred to was still in the future.